# Identification of a show episode about time stopping

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a TV show I saw in the early 80s, but it was old and I remember it black and white.
It really felt like an episode of the Twilight Zone (It's not the glitched stopwatch episode).

A man was pursued by another man / creature and when he/it was getting close, time would slow down and stop. Only them two would be 'live' for some chasing until the main character could go away.

One of the scenes I remember is that he was in a street and two boys were playing with dice. As one drops the dice, they slow down falling and time is stopped.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeStandsStill

Comment: why the downvotes? it would be nice to get an idea

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a bit like the Outer Limits episode "Premonition" because of the whole time-stop aspect.  Don't remember the dice thing, though.  There were two people and real time is catching up with them and there was a guy stuck there.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667846/?ref_=ttep_ep16

Comment: I just watched that episode; it was interesting, but that's not it